# Reusing similar code in Golang without generics

Tags: go, generics, software-design

Given that I have a MyMap variable of type

```
*map[uuid.UUID][]*Thing
```

and a piece of code like this:

```
h.MyMap[id] = append(h.MyMap[id], &thingA)

// other stuff with MyMap like this, later:

h.MyMapp[id][k] = &thingB

// and so on... the actual code is way more complex
```

and an identical code like above, except the fact it uses a map of type:

```
*map[int64][]*Thing
```

Is there a Golang way to DRY it and write a helper that does the similar code in one place?

Thank you.

Comment: Trying to find abstractions for simple assignments takes it one or two steps too far, if you ask me.

Comment: The actual code is way more complex, this is a simplified example.

Comment: The approach used by [sort.Sort](https://godoc.org/sort#Sort) can dry out code in some circumstances, but there's not enough information in the question to know if the technique is applicable.  It might help to show more of the complex code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

> [I]s there a Golang way to DRY it and write a helper that does the similar code in one place?

No.